# What is wrong with this desert rose and how can I cure it?

Tags: diagnosis

[image]

My desert rose appears to have a disease, as shown in the picture above. Every year, the leaves develop these spots and look terrible.  It still blooms every year.

Here is another picture of it:

[image]

Can anyone identify the disease and/or suggest a cure?

Comment: How long have you had this plant?  How much light is it getting? Looks like it could use a lot more.  Also, what water source are you using?  Is your water softened or is it well water?  The brown tips of the leaves might be caused by salt buildup. I'd use distilled or bottled water, only.  This plant looks like it needs to be re-potted in fresh, potting soil.  Are you growing this as a bonsai?  Otherwise, definitely new pot (a few inches larger only!), sterilized potting soil (with bacteria and mychorrhizae fungi added by company).

Comment: What's your watering regime up to the time when the problem starts? Do you leave the plant sitting in water, or get water on the leaves when you do irrigate, particularly late in the day?

Answer (score 1):

Could be rust. There are many products available to treat rust, and you can find recipes for solutions you can make at home too. Also it looks a little pot-bound, perhaps replant it in a larger pot and give it some fertiliser/nutrients as it may be hungry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like water spots, mine had that after being hit by my sprinkler system to often. Also, might have spider mites. Look for webs, and pick up some of the small dark spots with a Q tip and look at under a magnifying glass. The spider mites usually are found on the underside of the leaf, but the damage will show on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be lack of nutrients,

1. Remove almost 8cm of top soil.
2. Mix 2 to 3 fist full of soil + vermicompost + 3 to 4 table spoon of EPSOM Salt (All mixed well together.)
3. Add this mixture to top soil area, moisten the tops soil with mist of water, just misting, not watering.
4. You can spray EPSOM SALT quarter of a table spoon mixed well in half litre of water and spray on leaves every alternate day

You should see results in a week or 2